# Overriding onDraw method of imageView un-centers drawable

Tags: android-imageview, android, android-custom-view, ondraw

I was following this tutorial http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html to make and imageview that can scroll in all directions. The problem is when I override the onDraw method and try to draw the drawable right to the canvas manually the drawable is off center.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    getDrawable().draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();

}
```

if I comment out the method then the image is displayed centered in the middle correctly.

does overriding this method do something with the alignment?

Comment: after canvas.save() call canvas.concat with a Matrix taken by getImageMatrix()

Comment: that did the trick if you post an answer i can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

After `canvas.save()` call `canvas.concat` with a Matrix taken by `getImageMatrix()`

P.S: Taken from pskink's comment, as this seems to have solved Brian's issue, I'm positing this as a separate answer so future readers can see it.